# Having problems creating a new project in Zend Studio 7.0.2 (ubuntu 9.10)

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, permissions, zend-studio

I've just installed Zend Studio 7.0.2 on my Linux-Ubuntu 9.10 system. There were no problems during the installation but when I try to create a new project, the 'New Project' form hangs when I click the 'Finish' button. I can cancel the form but no project is created.

I suspect it may be a permissions problem!?

I have Zend Studio installed in:
`/home/myname/Zend/ZendStudio-7.0.2`

And the workspace in:
 
`/home/myname/Zend/workspace`

The perms for these dirs are:
drwxrwxrwx  4 myname myname 4096 2009-11-09 15:09 workspace
drwxrwxrwx 12 myname myname 4096 2009-11-09 15:10 ZendStudio-7.0.2

I'm quite new to linux so I'm probably missing something really obvious.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I can't create a new project?

Many thanks,
Josh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not that the form hangs - it's because the finish button doesn't gets clicked. This is an issue with Ubuntu 9.10 and Eclipse 3.5 (Zend studio is based on Eclipse).

The simple solution is to use the spacebar to press those buttons (the "New Project" Finish button isn't the only one).

However - there is a solution here:
http://blog.export.be/2009/10/fixing-eclipse-for-ubuntu-karmic-koala-9-10/

Comment: Fantastic!
Worked like a charm.
Thanks for the quick response.
This site rocks :)